# IWYU change selected gcc installation

Tags: c++, gcc, iwyu

Include What You Use is failing to lint files with c++ 17 headers. It reports an error that it can not find them.

When I run `iwyu -v` it says it is using devtoolset 7 but I have devtoolset 11 installed and I want it to use 11 instead.

```
$ iwyu -v
clang version 12.0.1
...
Found candidate GCC installation: /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7
Selected GCC installation: /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7
...
```

How do I get IWYU to use a different version of gcc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a clang option, `-gcc-toolchain`, which takes the path to a gcc toolchain. The path should be to the `usr` directory. Adding this option fixed the issue

```bash
$ iwyu -gcc-toolchain /opt/rh/devtoolset-ll/root/usr
```